# Keyframes unintentionally shared between shaders (Blender 2.8)

Tags: shaders, keyframes

I'm trying to animate multiple materials by keyframing the Color properties; however, for some reason the keyframes end up being shared between some materials, even though the material Name is different. The problem occurs regardless of whether the keyframes are locked. The materials in which this problem occurs are copies of each other. How do I unlink the keyframes? Does this have something to do with linking the material to the object or to the object's "Data" (though I'm not sure what this refers to)?

The screenshot shows two materials with what looks like same Shader Nodetree.
[image]